# Cannot force web server to reload image from disk

Tags: javascript, php, html, server, lamp

## Background

My goal is to build a web server that displays a slideshow of pages. Some slides may be only an image, other some text with css.

### Security

Nothing fancy, it's not going to be exposed to the outside world.

### Interface

Users must be able to modify the text in the text slides.

Users must be able to modify the images displayed on slides.

Images must be changeable in an automated way (another machine on the network creates an image and should be able to push that image to the server for display. Or, the server should be able to download the image itself, either way).

## What I've got

Knowing very little in this domain, I started reading and tinkering. A LAMP server seemed simple enough.

I've copied a [slideshow container from w3](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp) (which I later realized was an bad source according to knowledgeable people), and removed stuff I didn't need.

I created:

- forms for users to enter text, saved in plain text files (well, that was working before I updated Ubuntu, I guess a package upgrade broke something, now the forms only show the raw php code. Edit: needed to reenable the mods, probably because php upgraded from 5 to 7: `sudo a2enmod php7.2`).
- my own text slide in html, reading from the files. It was a hassle to make it read from the files when modified. I think that `txtFile.setRequestHeader('pragma', 'no-cache');` is what did it.
- a slide with a local image

## My actual real question

Copying a new image in place of the file used as input for the image slide does not change the image showed by the server. This seems to be a common problem, and there are several solutions proposed over the year. None of these I managed to make work. Random strings at the end of the file and address (hard to automate?), this piece in my index.html head:

```
+    <!-- attempt to reload images on change, does not work: -->
+    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
+    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
+    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

It also seems browsers, at least chrome, got more and more restrictive when it comes to avoid caching.

So in my setup (Ubuntu 18.04, the apt packages for a LAMP, and a recent chrome), how do I make my server reload the image from disk, when displaying the slide?

Edit: I don't want to hit refresh, the server should reload the image automatically.

## Another vague question which may actually be the culprit

Am I doing things strangely? It feels developing this is more cumbersome than it ought to be, so that I might be on the wrong track. Would you guide me to another, more sense making direction?

Comment: I think image versioning is your best option. Whenever your users upload a new image, put that information in the database (if you have one) and use the ID of that row to make your cache bursting. Something like `<img src="{{image.url}}?v={{image.id}}">`

Comment: I'd try to serve the images via a php file: `<img src="getImage.php?id=xy">`. In my experience (without heavy testing) they don't get cached then.

Comment: What might be an interesting approach is using AJAX in a continuous loop to fetch the slider's images. That way they're continuesly updated even without a page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to disable browser cache. While, in principle, caching is quite simple: browser saves loaded resources and serves them from memory on subsequent requests, disabling it cross browser/cross device is rather complicated.

The simplest thing you can do is to append a unique param to your image, to trick the browser into believing it's a different one:

```
<img src="/path/to/image.jpg?v=<?php time(); ?>">
```

This will make your browser always load the `<img>` because it will think it's a new file. However, disabling browser cache, especially for images is a huge hit on performance.

---

A better approach is to assign unique identifiers to your images and save them (in a database), so their unique param only changes when the file has been changed.

---

Here's a way to do it without a database, since all you need to know is the time the image was last replaced:

- in your image upload processing script, upon successful upload, also write current timestamp in a file on server (i.e.: `timestamp.txt`).
- in your markup, use the contents of this file to mark your image(s):
  `<img src="path/to/file.jpg?v=<?= file_get_contents('./timestamp.txt'); ?>">`
- make an ajax call reading `timestamp.txt` every few seconds. When contents of `timestamp.txt` differ from the `v` param of your `src`, replace `src` value with the new timestamp, causing the browser to instantly reload the file.
  **Note:** the ajax itself will get cached unless you make sure it does not:
  `'timestamp.txt?v=' + new Date().getTime()`

Comment: But then, how do I automatically update the page source to take in the new unique identifier? I'm missing something.

Comment: @Gauthier: when you upload the file you create a unique identifier and save it in db. When you serve the image, you query the db to get the identifier. When you overwrite the image, you replace the identifier. This way images that haven't been changed are cached. The ones that changed are reloaded.

Comment: @Gauthier - one more thing: you don't need to append the identifier to the file name saved on server. The name can remain the original. As in `file.jpg` and `file.jbg?v=bogus` will both load `file.jpg`.

Comment: Ok, what remains is to get started with db. It looks like I cannot just overwrite the image file, someone has to tell the server its a new version...

Comment: It's not the server that doesn't know it. It's the browser. And now you're engineering a mechanism for the server to be able to tell the browser: *"hey, this one changed. reload it!"*

Comment: Your solution of `<?php time(); ?>` did not work, sadly. That's what I've been reading everywhere, and I don't get why the image isn't reloaded since this `v=` suffix should change all the time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171799/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-gauthier).

Answer (score 0):

You can force web-server to reload an image from disk by changing its URL. Since you do not want to change its name or path very often, you will give a v parameter for it, like:

```
<img src="/images/myimage.png?v=2">
```

and if you want to reload it again, then change it to

```
<img src="/images/myimage.png?v=3">
```

and so on.

Comment: But I don't want to manually change the html, or even hit refresh. A new version of the image should show in the slide by itself.

Comment: @Gauthier That's why I advised you to use Ajax. You can use PHP in the backend to retrieve the images you want and let JS update the DOM. No need to manually update any source or refresh the page.

Comment: @Gauthier you can put there any version you want from server-side if you want to reload the image. If you want to reload the image all the time, make sure you put there something which is always different. If you want to change the image when it was already loaded, just change the value of v using Javascript.